Is there any backup solution host machines that act like saving states in Virtual Machines?
I am looking for a backup solution that is similar to VMWare's or Proxmox saving states.
For example in VMWare/Promox I can save the state of the Virtual Machine then I can mess stuff and revert back like nothing happened.
This has saved me a lot of time when I'm experimenting and I'm looking for similar solutions.
I am using on my laptop Ubuntu Desktop 23.10.
